# Why doesn't passing attributes to Model.new work?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a model `WordpressBlogger` that has these attributes: (note the specific order of these columns: screen_name was added AFTER the table was generated)

```
id, rss_feed_id, blog_url, year_founded, created_at, updated_at, screen_name, latest_entry
```

When I do `blogger = WordpressBlogger.new(:screen_name => "test")` in my console, it doesn't seem to return a model with the screen_name set.

Instead I get this:

```
=> #<WordpressBlogger id: nil, rss_feed_id: nil, blog_url: nil, year_founded: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, screen_name: nil, latest_entry: nil>
```

Yet, when I do `blogger = WordpressBlogger.new(:year_founded => 2011)` in my console, it returns a model with this attribute set.

```
=> #<WordpressBlogger id: nil, rss_feed_id: nil, blog_url: nil, year_founded: 2011, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, screen_name: nil, latest_entry: nil>
```

Is this a weird Rails bug where the attribute doesn't get set if the column in the database is AFTER Rails-created attributes such as `created_at` and `updated_at`?

UPDATE: I forgot to add it to attr_accessible.

Comment: can you include your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, there is a reference to [attr_accessible](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible) in the `WordpressBlogger` class.  You probably need to add year_founded to the list of attr_accessible elements that are allowed bulk assignment.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not creating the Model. Notice there's no `id` set. To create it you must either

```
blogger = WordpressBlogger.new(:screen_name => "test")
blogger.save
```

or

```
blogger = WordpressBlogger.create(:screen_name => "test")
```

Is this in your model?

```
attr_accessor :screen_name, :year_founded
```

Or you may have to `exit` and run `rails c` again

Comment: I know it's not actually created. I'm talking about the output of the model in the Rails console after I execute those statements. Which shows the current Model state.

Comment: So if you create it or save it, the actual model is created or saved? or do you get an error?

Comment: That's not really my question at this point. I know what to do to get them saved.

Comment: What i'm getting at is the mass assignment error. I want to see if it gets raised. That implies that in your model you're not declaring `attr_accessor :screen_name, :year_founded`

Comment: They get saved. But with screen_name of nil even though I set it.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably have the console running when you ran your migrations.  A quick `reload!` or restart of the console should make all columns visible.

Comment: i misunderstood the question. I thought the columns after the timestamps are not visible in the console. can you update your question with your model?